# Load word file to t-sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a word file from the state that contains non-standard field and line delimiters.  I have a old Stored Procedure that takes the content of the file (not the file itself) and breaks it apart to be used.  What I need is a way to read the file into T-SQL into the text variable for the SP to work as some of these files are over a hundred pages long.  I have used the Bulk Insert command in the past but I need to read the file into a varchar(max) or Varbinary(max) as each field in a line of code uses s unique set of letters to distinguish that field.

I was able to use the following code to read the document but I need to add a variable so that is will be usable by other:

```
declare @myString varchar(max); 

Select @myString  = BulkColumn
from OPENROWSET(Bulk '<File Network Location>\<File Name>', SINGLE_BLOB) as x 

exec csp_Reader @myString, 1
```

What I need is for the File Network Location to be hard coded and the File Name to be entered by the user.

Comment: So you want to load the _text_ (not binary) content of a Word document into a varchar(max) column of a table?

Comment: would it also be viable for you to read that word-document's content in, say, `c#.net` and then pass that to your stored procedure from there? I imagine it easier that way, because I don't think you have lots of office-supporting functions in `T-SQL` directly

Comment: More like a variable - it would be one field with the text from the word document in that field.  The SP would then break up the varchar(max) field into a temp table to then be stored and retrieved.

Comment: You can only use the network file location if your SQL Server has it mapped.

Comment: I can successfully run the Exec if I hard code both the path and the File name what I am trying to do is find a way to have the path hard coded and the file name be a variable that others can enter though SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic469199-5-1.aspx with a little modifications as followed:

```
Declare @filename   varchar(100) = 'FileName',
        @UnPaidOnly bit = 1

DECLARE @filepath varchar(100)
Declare @sql as varchar(max)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp
create table #Temp
(
    myString varchar(max)
)
Set @filepath = '\\<Network File Path>\' + @filename + '.277'

Set @sql = '
insert into #Temp  select BulkColumn
from OPENROWSET(Bulk ''' + @filepath + ''', Single_Blob) as tt'           

Exec (@sql)

declare @myString varchar(max)

set @myString = (select t.myString from #Temp t)

exec csp_Reader @myString, @UnPaidOnly 
drop table #Temp
```